# Adding values list of tuples on the basis of key

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples, consider tuple's 1st element as key and second one as value.

```
Input: [[(1, 100), (2, 100), (3, 100)], [(1, 100), (4, 100), (5, 100)]]
Output: [(1, 200), (2, 100), (3, 100), (4, 100), (5, 100)]
```

I am a bit new to python, unable to start off with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)
data = [[(1, 100), (2, 100), (3, 100)], [(1, 100), (4, 100), (5, 100)]]
for i in data:
    for k, v in i:
        res[k] += v
print(list(res.items()))
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 200), (2, 100), (3, 100), (4, 100), (5, 100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

guessing your question...is how to get them into one list and to eliminate duplicate key's?

```
 storeNewList = []

 for item in storedList:
     for key, value in item.items():
           storeNewList[key] += value
 print(list(storeNewList.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach to the above problem can be

```
lis = [(1, 100), (2, 100), (3, 100), (1, 100), (4, 100), (5, 100)]
dic = {}
for i in lis:
    if i[0] not in dic.keys():
        dic.update({i[0] : i[1]})
    else:
        dic[i[0]] += i[1]
```

The code first checks if the key exists in the dictionary. If not, it adds the key-value pair. If it already exists (as in the case of second (1, 100)), it adds to the pre-existing value of that key.
The code outputs

```
{1: 200, 2: 100, 3: 100, 4: 100, 5: 100}
```